# WatiN: Need to find value contained in a div of SSRS report displayed in browser

Tags: c#, reporting-services, watin

I am using WatiN to launch an SSRS report, which gets displayed on a new browser window.I saw the HTML of the report and found that SSRS arranges it in a table.
I am interested in fetching the values of one TD(s)(which in the example below is 11,202.63):

```
<DIV class="r11">ARSystemBalance </DIV></TD><TD class="a67"><DIV class="r11">: 11,202.63</DIV>
```

What should be the best method to fetch this value ?

Comment: Are you asking how to render an SSRS report to an arbitrary window. If you have access to the DB used to generate the report it might be easier to create a proc that returns just the values you need. As far as parsing the output, you willhave to use client side scripting after the report has been rendered.

Comment: This question is about WatiN. My script is opening one SSRS report in browser and I want to fetch the values as descbibed in the question. I have also added WatiN as a tag.

Comment: Sorry, I read that as a typo for wanting. lol. Maybe there is a GetElementByAttribute or something similiar to parse out your value.

Comment: Is the label always consistent, such as `ARSystemBalance` or does that change as well?  Also, are you always going to need just one value from the SSRS report, or multiples?

Comment: @MauriceReeves It stays the same. I have to read this one value and a few other similar values with other labels

Answer (score 1):

We Also Faced same problem while creating test manager in waitin but then we over come this problem with  finding text in any given table and returning the tr from there 
please take help from following code which we wrote in C#

TableRow tr = table.TableCell(Find.ByText(regex)).ContainingTableRow;
                return tr;

thanks

Comment: Thanks Syed for your reply, I will just let you after trying that out.

Comment: There are lots of nested tables. How did you manage to find the right table, the one which actually contained the values ?

Answer (score 0):

following code snipt will may help you

TableRow SearchTable(string TableId, string data, int page)
        {
            Table table = ie.Table(Find.ById(TableId));

```
        Regex regex = new Regex(data + @".*");

        if (table.TableCell(Find.ByText(regex)).Exists)
        {
            TableRow tr = table.TableCell(Find.ByText(regex)).ContainingTableRow;
            return tr;

        }
        else
        {
            int n = table.Tables[table.Tables.Count - 1].Links.Count;
            if (page < n)
            {
                table.Tables.First().Links[page].Click();
                ie.WaitForComplete();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                return (SearchTable(TableId, data, page + 1));
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
```